# how to detect selected keyboard language in flutter ?

Tags: dart, keyboard, flutter

how to detect the current keyboard language while typing? I'm trying to implement a translation in chat app, I need to know which language the other user is typing in so I could know which text to translate based on the user native language

Comment: I don't know if it's what you're looking for: https://flutter.io/tutorials/internationalization/ You can get the location and know the language

Comment: I'm not sure if you can get their keyboard language, but you can use the [Google Cloud Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/detecting-language) once they've entered some text to get the language of the text.

Comment: @DomingoMG,  I yes I would get the current device language but I want a way of detecting the language to determine if I will be needing to translate or not, " in case of they speak the same language there will be no need to translate", I could use google translation API but for translation and language detection, but  I would rather not, because how much it  cost

Comment: Hi @OsamaGamal did you get answer to this

Answer (score 2):

There does not seem to be a way to do this in flutter currently.
I submitted an issue for it on GitHub - please upvote it if you would like to help it be triaged sooner.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25841

Answer (score 0):

void changeKeyboardLanguage(String languageCode) {
  SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.setLocale', languageCode);
}

try this guy

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

The solution is already provided in the github link.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart' as intl;

bool isRTL(String text) {
  return intl.Bidi.detectRtlDirectionality(text);
}[enter link description here][1]

child: Text(
  "Your Text Here",
  textDirection: isRTL("Your Text Here") ? TextDirection.rtl : TextDirection.ltr,
)
```