# how to detect device keyboard events in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

How can i detect keyboard events in flutter? Specifically, I want to detect if user changes language in device keyboard.I DON'T MEAN DEVICE LOCALIZATION. I mean the language inside keyboard. Thanks

Comment: its an issue in Github still and it is still open :(. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25841

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52689163/how-to-detect-selected-keyboard-language-in-flutter

Comment: @FurkanAydın Thanks. looks like we must still wait